# Spring Hibernate C3P0: Connections not released

Tags: hibernate, c3p0, spring-transactions

C3P0 is not releasing connections after a transaction completes.
Here's the stack trace:

> java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.
>      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:555)
>      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
>      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
>      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
>      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>      at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
>      at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
>      at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
>      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
>      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
>      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
>      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
>
> ...............
>      at com.ikoda.dao.user.UserDaoImpl.getUserChildByEmailPassword(UserDaoImpl.java:329)
>
> .....................................
>      at com.ikoda.service.springtransactions.AdminUserServiceImpl.doUserChildLoginByEmail(AdminUserServiceImpl.java:100)
>      at com.ikoda.service.springtransactions.AdminUserServiceImpl.doLoginByEmail(AdminUserServiceImpl.java:89)
>
> ..........................

The service methods called are as follows:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public User doLoginByEmail(String email, String password) throws UserStructureException
{
    User u = doUserMainLoginByEmail(email, password);
    if (null != u)
    {
        return u;
    }
    else
    {
        return doUserChildLoginByEmail(email, password);
    }
}




private UserMain doUserMainLoginByEmail(String email, String password) throws UserStructureException
{
    try
    {

        UserMain returnedUser = userDao.getUserMainByEmailPassword(email, password, DeliveryPropertiesSingleton.getInstance().getBusinessId());

        if (null != returnedUser && returnedUser.getPassword().equals(password))
        {

            return returnedUser;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe)
    {
      ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }

}


private  UserChild doUserChildLoginByEmail(String email, String password) throws UserStructureException
{
    try
    {


        UserChild returnedUser = userDao.getUserChildByEmailPassword(email, password, DeliveryPropertiesSingleton.getInstance().getBusinessId());

        if (null != returnedUser && returnedUser.getPassword().equals(password))
        {

            return returnedUser;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       ....
    }

}
```

The dao methods are as follows:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public UserMain getUserMainByEmailPassword(String email, String password, Long businessId)
{

    Session session = this.sessionFactory1.getCurrentSession();


    List<UserMain> result = session.createQuery("from UserMain where email like '" + email + "' and password like '" + password + "' and  businessid =" + businessId).list();

    if(result.size()==1)
    {
            UserMain u = result.get(0);

            return u;
    }
    return null;
}


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public UserChild getUserChildByEmailPassword(String email, String password, Long businessId)
{

    Session session = this.sessionFactory1.openSession();

    List<UserChild> result = session.createQuery("from UserChild where email like '" + email
            + "' and password like '" + password + "' and  businessid =" + businessId).list();

    if(result.size()==1)
    {
        UserChild u = result.get(0);

        return u;
    }
    return null;

}
```

The pool configuration and transaction configuration are as follows:

```html
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/xxx?useUnicode=true&#38;characterEncoding=utf8" />
  <property name="user" value="xxx" />
  <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx" />

  <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
  <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="45" />
  <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" />
 </bean>
```

```html
 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />

 </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Any advice would be deeply appreciated

Comment: c3p0 is telling you your application is not releasing Connections. it is helping you find an application problem, which it looks like you have found. (yay!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, dead simple.

The DAO methods used openSession which requires an explicit close. For spring/hibernate transaction managed persistence, it should be getCurrentSession