# c3p0 not being effective

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

My [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) is not honoring the sessions optimization of my application. The active sessions reaches the threshold (set as 800) and eventually the application has to be restarted. This should not happen when I have c3p0 set up in place.
My current set is as follows:

```
<!-- JDBC connection pool settings -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>

        <!-- The seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire -->
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">300</property>

        <!-- for Oracle set 'max_statements' to 0 set to 100 otherwise 
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>

        <!-- If this is a number greater than 0, c3p0 will test all idle, pooled but unchecked-out connections, every this number of seconds -->
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">120</property>

        <!-- Determines how many connections at a time c3p0 will try to acquire when the pool is exhausted -->
        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property>
```

Jars used:

- `hibernate-c3p0-4.2.1.Final.jar`
- `c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar`
- `mchange-commons-java-0.2.11`

Database: Oracle

My questions are:

1. How will my c3p0 setup be effective?
2. Is there some additional parameter required for optimization? shall
   I use some more properties in the production environment?

Comment: Why restarted?  Please show errors.

Comment: You might have a different problem. It will indeed reach your maximum threshold if you use that many connections concurrently, but it should kill them off after some time of being idle.

Comment: Do I need to change the connection provider class name with current jars implemented? And use hibernate.c3p0.* instead the property used above(c3p0.*)?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Here are my errors: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException: Could not open connection

Comment: You show a maximum of 100 Connections. What do you mean by "active sessions reaches the threshold (set as 800)"? What happens when you reach it. It's very likely that what you have is a Connection leak. See [c3p0's docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900344/c3p0-deadlocks-in-hibernate for how to address this.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am still doubtful If I am using the correct provider class name , properties name with respect to current relevant jars being used. Could you please revisit them once.