# Hibernate/c3p0 : Connection pool is full : "pool is already maxed out" error

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, c3p0

I work with Hibernate and c3p0 to manage DAO in my application.

There is problem after a while : the application, more precisely BDD requests, does not work. Reason : the connection pool is full.

I have the following messages :

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - acquire test -- pool is already maxed out. [managed: 20; max: 20]
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@240ab5e6 [managed: 20, unused: 0, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@547a79cf)
```

It seems that connections are never closed, in the log file we can see that the connection pool is filled at each request until it reaches the maximum (20, see the error above) :

```
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (LogicalConnectionImpl.java:226) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:587) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - acquire test -- pool size: 16; target_pool_size: 16; desired target? 17
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:450) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 1
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1788) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - Starting acquisition series. Incremented pending_acquires [1],  attempts_remaining: 30
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:236) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@67c8303a: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@232613e3
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1390) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - awaitAvailable(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@547a79cf
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@240ab5e6 [managed: 16, unused: 0, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@547a79cf)
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v3o059n1wfndya61hxar|3b29a008]-HelperThread-#1] DEBUG (GooGooStatementCache.java:333) com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 45; checked out: 0; num connections: 16; num keys: 45
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v3o059n1wfndya61hxar|3b29a008]-HelperThread-#1] DEBUG (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:283) com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@58b73780.acquireResource() returning. 
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v3o059n1wfndya61hxar|3b29a008]-HelperThread-#1] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@240ab5e6 [managed: 17, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@547a79cf)
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v3o059n1wfndya61hxar|3b29a008]-HelperThread-#1] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:471) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - decremented pending_acquires: 0
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v3o059n1wfndya61hxar|3b29a008]-HelperThread-#1] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1825) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - Acquisition series terminated successfully. Decremented pending_acquires [0],  attempts_remaining: 30
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@240ab5e6 [managed: 17, unused: 0, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@547a79cf)
[2017/05/11 10:06:48] [http-bio-0.0.0.0-20443-exec-4] DEBUG (LogicalConnectionImpl.java:232) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
```

I have set up the following configuration for c3p0 :

```
hibernate.connection.release_mode=on_close
hibernate.c3p0.validate=true
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1;
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=3000
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
```

And this is an example of how I make request :

```
public static void updateSignatureLogin(String login, int transactionId) {
    createEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    IsignSignaturetraceEntity dbsignature = entityManager.find(IsignSignaturetraceEntity.class, transactionId);
    dbsignature.setLogin(login);
    entityManager.persist(dbsignature);
    entityManager.merge(dbsignature);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

What is the problem ? The way I manage connection/request in the code or configuration of c3p0 ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67588721/32453

Answer (score 1):

A few things I see here are:

1. You're using hibernate.connection.release_mode=on_close which will hang on to connections for the duration of the hibernate session. Look here for additional options for that setting: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Web_Server/1.0/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/transactions-connection-release.html
2. You are manually managing your transaction boundaries rather than allowing a transaction manager to do that for you. If you're using Spring, you can configure declarative transaction management. See here for more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html
3. Your connection pool has a max of just 20 connections. Check the application usage data to determine if that is a reasonable number. Depending on your hardware and usage, you could find that 20 connections is too low even for the min_size.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have changed some properties : `release_mode=after_transaction`
 `hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300` and `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=120`.
In the log file I see that it checks the connections but it changes nothing, I have already the error "maxed out error" : 
`com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - BEGIN check for expired resources.
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - FINISHED check for expired resources.
pool is already maxed out. [managed: 20; max: 20]`

Comment: I think that the connections pool is not "cleaned", the connections are still alive. I have kept the max connections number of just 20 for testing. For the moment, increase the number of the max number of connections it not a solution, at any time the pool will be full.

Comment: Try to make `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` - when connection is expires and destroyed large and `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period` small - to detect problems earlier. Also you can use jstack to see, if pool threads jams.